# Error using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration, sftp

I need to create an application that transfers files from local to remote SFTP server. I have to do it using Spring Integration, I followed the documentation but I have not been able to make it works. When I run it always get the error:

```
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager main
    SEVERE: exporting...
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager exportFile
    INFO: <<< at SftpFileManager.exportFile >>>
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager exportFile
    INFO: SftpFileManager.localDirectory => C:\temp\test\test.xml
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@351787ea: startup date [Mon May 15 12:15:37 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/integration/SftpFileManager-context.xml]
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties
    INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
    may 15, 2017 12:15:37 PM org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar registerHeaderChannelRegistry
    INFO: No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
    INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [sftp.properties]
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerErrorChannel
    INFO: No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerTaskScheduler
    INFO: No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties
    INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler initialize
    INFO: Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
    INFO: Starting beans in phase -2147483648
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
    INFO: Starting beans in phase 0
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent
    INFO: Adding {message-handler:sftpOutboundAdapter} as a subscriber to the 'inputChannel' channel
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary
    INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@351787ea.inputChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer start
    INFO: started sftpOutboundAdapter
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent
    INFO: Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary
    INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@351787ea.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer start
    INFO: started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connecting to REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connection established
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
    may 15, 2017 12:15:38 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    WARNING: Permanently added 'REMOTE.IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:39 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:52 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Disconnecting from REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connecting to REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connection established
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Host 'REMOTE.IP' is known and matches the RSA host key
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
    may 15, 2017 12:15:53 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: password
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Disconnecting from REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connecting to REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Connection established
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server: 
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: none
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client: 
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Host 'REMOTE.IP' is known and matches the RSA host key
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    may 15, 2017 12:16:07 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
    may 15, 2017 12:16:08 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Next authentication method: password
    may 15, 2017 12:16:20 PM com.jcraft.jsch log
    INFO: Disconnecting from REMOTE.IP port 22
    may 15, 2017 12:16:20 PM com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager exportFile
    SEVERE: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
```

I checked the credentials but that is not the problem. Could you please help me? or share me an example?

My configuration:
**SftpFileManager-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            "
            >

         <!-- <import resource="SftpCommon.xml"/>  --> 

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:sftp.properties"/>

        <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="defaultsftpSessionFactory" />
            <property name="poolSize" value="${poolSize}"/>
            <property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="${sessionWaitTimeout}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sftpFileManager" class="com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager" />

        <bean id="defaultsftpSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
            <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
            <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
            <property name="user" value="${username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${password}"/>

            <!--  <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true"/> -->
        </bean>

        <int:channel id="inputChannel"/>

        <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
                    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                    channel="inputChannel"
                    remote-file-separator="/"
                    remote-directory="${remote.directory}"
                    mode="REPLACE">
            <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice" >
                    <property name="retryPolicy">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                            <property name="maxAttempts" value="${retry.maxAttempts}" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean> -->
                <int:retry-advice />
            </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

        <bean id="fileNameGenerator" class="org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator" />

        <bean id="SftpFileManager" class="com.test.tt.file.sftp.out.SftpFileManager">
          <property name="inputChannel" ref="inputChannel" />
        </bean> 
    </beans>
```

**My class SftpFileManager.java**

```
    public class SftpFileManager {


        protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SftpFileManager.class);
        private MessageChannel inputChannel;


        public boolean exportFile(String pathName) throws Exception {

            log.info("<<< at SftpFileManager.exportFile >>>");

            log.info("SftpFileManager.localDirectory => " + pathName);

            final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpFileManager-context.xml");

            try {
                final File file = new File(pathName);
                Assert.isTrue(file.exists(), String.format("File '%s' does not exist.", pathName));
                final Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
                inputChannel = context.getBean("inputChannel", MessageChannel.class);
                inputChannel.send(message); 

                log.info(String.format("Successfully transferred '%s' file to a " + " server under the name '%s'",
                        pathName, pathName));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                log.error(ex);

            } finally {

            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void main(String [] args){

            try{
            SftpFileManager sftp = new SftpFileManager();
            log.error("exporting...");
            sftp.exportFile("C:\\temp\\test\\test.xml");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.error("SftpFileManageraa.Error!!!!!!!!!!!" + ex);
            }
        }

        public MessageChannel getInputChannel() {
            return inputChannel;
        }

        public void setInputChannel(MessageChannel inputChannel) {
            this.inputChannel = inputChannel;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250057/spring-integration-sftp-jsch-session-disconnects)?

Comment: HI @AxelKemper Thanks for the aswering. Yes, I have been that post I set the poolsize=500 and sessionTimeOut=100000 but it still does not work...

Comment: Inspect the log messages of the remote SFTP server and find out why it can't open additional SFTP sessions. Increase remote log level, if necessary. Could be exhausted resources, failure to close existing sessions, firewall issues, ... SFTP is not easy to debug. Perhaps you can persuade a network admin to help with a protocol analysis to get to know what is going on.